random vector with parameters in R
I'm trying to generate a random dataset in R. I am starting with a block-level (as in city blocks) dataset which has a manzent variable (block ID), a population variable, and a scholarity variable (avg of n years of education per person; range 0:14). I need this data at a person level, not block, so I need to generate random persons per block while maintaining the block-level values; this means that each unique manzent will be generating n = population rows with a random scholarity value, such that mean(scholarity) for that block == original scholarity value.
So if I have:
i <- sample(unique(original_df$manzent), 1)
one_row <- original_df[original_df$manzent == i]

target_mean <- one_row$scholarity[1]
n <- one_row$population[1]
min_val <- 0
max_val <- 14

names(one_row)
# > manzent, population, scholarity

I would need to make a new persons datset such that mean(persons$scholarity) == target_mean (or at least is within a range of T tolerance, for example .001), and nrow(persons) == n. The scholarity persons$scholarity MUST have only POSITIVE INTEGERS within min_value:max_value, which is one of my main constraints.
I could not find a package that does this with this many parameters, and rnorm() falls short of what I need because of decimals.
Any ideas?
Thank you for your time! :)

In a different part of the code I needed to do this with sum instead of mean. This is what I came up with:
total_vector <- function(target, n, min_val, max_val) {
  
  v <- sample(min_val:max_val, n - 1, replace = T)
  s <- sum(v)
  xrange = target - s
  
  switch = T
  
  while (switch) {
    
    if (s < target & xrange < max_val) {
      
      v <- c(v, xrange)
      switch = F
      
    } else {
      
      v <- sample(min_val:max_val, n - 1, replace = T)
      s <- sum(v)
      xrange = target - s
      
    }
    
  }
  
  return(v)
  
}

However, a similar approach for the mean only resulted in R running forever trying to find a valid vector.

Yeah, the normal distribution is continuous and unbounded. You want a bounded  discrete distribution, so rnorm isn't a good choice.  I'd just use sample and set the prob argument to values that get the summary statistics you want, e.g. sample(0:14, size = one_row$population[1], prob = ...). If you have any real data to base this on, you could use a frequency table of actual values as the prob argument.

"such that  mean(persons$scholarity) == target_mean (or at least is within a range of T tolerance, for example .001)". If you're serious about that tolerance, then you don't actually want a fully random process. Random numbers tend to be much more random that that. You can simulate 1000 draws from a normal distribution and take the mean withmean(rnorm(1000)). Do that 100k times mm = replicate(1e5, mean(rnorm(1000))) and see how many sample means are within 0.001 of the true population mean of 0, sum(abs(mm) < .001). When I ran that, I got 2570 of them, so 2.57% of them...

If you want the sample means to be that close to pre-determined values, then you want a semi-random process where you draw, say, 95% of the values randomly and then attempt to deterministically calculate the remaining values to get the mean where you need it to be. That or you need to set up a while loop that keep doing fully random draws until you get one that meets your specifications--but if your specifications are too tight this might take a long time, as you saw.

Calculate n*target_mean, then divvy up the resulting scholarity points among the n individuals in the block. If you want to hit a target distribution of scholarity by individual, you can probably get close with rmultinom. A reproducible example with some dummy data would probably help you get more code-based responses.
